# Django celery register periodic task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I'm using **Celery 4.4** with **Django 2.2**

I have to create a **Periodic Task**, I'm extending **PeriodicTask** ask as

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import PeriodicTask

class IncompleteOrderHandler(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = crontab(
        minute='*/{}'.format(getattr(settings, 'INCOMPLETE_ORDER_HANDLER_PULSE', 5))
    )

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Task definition
        eligible_users, slot_begin, slot_end = self.get_users_in_last_slot()
        map(lambda user: self.process_user(user, slot_begin, slot_end), eligible_users)
```

Earlier to register the above task, I used to call

```
from celery.registry import tasks

tasks.register(IncompleteOrderHandler)
```

But now there is no `registry` module in the `celery`. How can I register the above periodic task?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with class based celery tasks. This has to works, but it doesn't!
Accidentally, my problem solved by every one on these two changes:

1. I import one of the class based tasks at tasks.py in viewsets.py, and suddenly i figured out that after doing that, celery found all of the tasks at tasks.py.
2. This was my base celery setting file:

   ```
   from __future__ import absolute_import
   import os
   from celery import Celery
   from django.conf import settings

   os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'picha.settings')
   app = Celery('picha')
   app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
   app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   ```

   I changed the last line to `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: 
   settings.CELERY_TASKS)` and add CELERY_TASKS list to settings.py and write all 
   tasks.py file paths in it and then celery found tasks.

I hope one of these work for you.